How to create a custom container?

I'm looking for a solution for the opposite design:
The right side shape in left side
How to do ?
class CustomPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = new Path();
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width - 10, size.height / 2);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}


Can you add just a bit of context? Because, if the goal is just to put some color to the right side, you could simply have a parent container with a different color. Otherwise, it's a bit more complex.

You can try this solution:
class CustomPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = new Path();
    path.lineTo(10, size.height / 2);  
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);       
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);    
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}


Please explain how this would solve the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers
